# How to convert html text to Plain Text in report

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I am passing HTML text as parameter value in java. like

```
parameter.put("TEMP_TEXT","<p>test</P>");
```

I have bound this parameter in ireport as static text field like `$P{TEMP_TEXT}` then it will be converted in plain text.

```
output ought to be 'test'
```

Which setting need to be added on *staticText* in *iReport* for acquire same?

Comment: use this <PRE><p>test</p></PRE> and let me know if it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a Text Field to your report.

```
Text Field Expression : $P{TEMP_TEXT}
Markup : html
```